# RootViewController doesn't populate after Xcode 7 update

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

After upgrading to the latest Xcode, my App stopped populating the RootViewController with data. However when I click to next screen and go back, all the data is there. I haven't been able to figure this out, so I put the code snippets below:

```
- (void)startLoading
{
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;

    HUD.delegate = self;

    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadInBackground) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"navigationController = %@", [navigationController view]);

}
- (void)loadInBackground
{
    //Copy database to the user's phone if needed.
    [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];

    [self populateFromDatabase];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishedLoading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)finishedLoading
{

    //back on the main thread now, it's safe to show your view controller
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self startLoading];

}
```

...

```
- (void) populateFromDatabase {

    // Init the Array
    activeCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    activeSubjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    activeQuotes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    subjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    quotes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    quoteMaps = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //this is not currently getting the category filled up with anything
    [Category getInitialDataToDisplay:[self getDBPath]];
```

...

```
@implementation Category 

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        subjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    }
    return self;
}


+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

    NSLog(@"getInitialDataToDisplay is loading data...");

    // Use this section to bring in database and populate the array
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];    
    [database open];

    QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //POPULATE THE QUOTES 
    FMResultSet *result_quotes = [database executeQuery:@"select * from QUOTE"];

    while([result_quotes next]) {

        //for some reason q is not instantiated and shows up as nil
        Quote *q = [Quote alloc];

        q.quote_id = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"QUOTE_ID"];
        q.quote_date = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"DATE"];
        q.title = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"DESC1"];
        q.desc2 = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"DESC2"];
        q.excerpt = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"EXCERPT"];
        q.note = [result_quotes stringForColumn:@"NOTES"];
        q.isDirty = NO;

        [appDelegate.quotes addObject:q];
//        [q release];

    }
```

...

One thing I noticed is that when I break on the "Quote *q = [Quote alloc];" line the q is nil.

[image]

Any advice or direction in solving this would be appreciated.

Here is the Quote init method:

```
#import "Quote.h"
#import "QuotesAppDelegate.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "FMResultSet.h"

@implementation Quote

@synthesize quote_id, quote_date, isDirty, title, desc2, excerpt, note;


//- (id) initWithPrimaryKey:(NSInteger) pk {
//  
//  [super init];
////    quote_id = pk;
//      quote_id = [pk stringValueof];
//  
//  return self;
//}

- (void) addQuote {

    // This step will involve both inserting a new record into the quote_map table as well as the quote table. 
    // Will need the new quote_id first and then will need a new quote_map_id and with these grab the subject_id and insert a new quote_map

    QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:appDelegate.getDBPath];    

    //    NSNumber *myNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.subject_id];

    NSLog(@"Quote addQuote: QUOTE_ID/DESC1/DESC2/EXCERPT = %@ / %@ / %@ / %@", self.quote_id , self.title, self.desc2, self.excerpt);

    NSInteger quoteInt = [self.quote_id intValue];

    if ([database open]) {
        [database executeUpdate:@"insert into QUOTE(quote_id, desc1, desc2, date, excerpt) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:quoteInt], self.title, self.desc2, self.quote_date, self.excerpt];

        [database close];
    }

}

- (void) deleteQuote {

    QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:appDelegate.getDBPath];    

    NSInteger quoteIdInt = [self.quote_id intValue];

    if ([database open]) {

        [database executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM QUOTE WHERE quote_id = ?", 
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:quoteIdInt]];

        [database executeUpdate:@"DELETE FROM QUOTE_MAP WHERE quote_id = ?", 
         [NSNumber numberWithInt:quoteIdInt]];

        [database close];
    }

}


- (NSInteger)getNextQuoteId {

    QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:appDelegate.getDBPath];    
    [database open];

    FMResultSet *rst = [database executeQuery:@"select max(quote_id) + 1 AS QUOTE_ID from QUOTE"];

    [rst next];

    NSLog(@"PRINT FIRST QUOTE_ID = %d", [rst intForColumn:@"QUOTE_ID"]);

    NSInteger nextId = [rst intForColumnIndex:0];
    [database close];

    NSLog(@"NEW QUOTE_ID = %ld", (long)nextId);

    //    NSInteger myInt = [nextSubId intValue];

    return nextId;

    //    [maxSubjectId release];

}


- (void) saveAllData {

    if(isDirty) {

        QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:appDelegate.getDBPath];    

        if (self.quote_id > 0){

            if ([database open]) {

                NSLog(@"QUOTE_ID/DESC1/DESC2/EXCERPT = %@ / %@ / %@ / %@", self.quote_id , self.title, self.desc2, self.excerpt);

                [database executeUpdate:@"update QUOTE Set desc1 = ?, desc2 = ?, date = ?, excerpt = ? where quote_id = ?", 
                 self.title, self.desc2, self.quote_date, self.excerpt, self.quote_id];

                [database close];
            }

            isDirty = NO;
        }

    }

}

@end
```

---

Here is the view:

```
@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize categories, qmv,  selectedQuote, selectedSubject, subjects, allCategories, allSubjects, mySection, myRow, checkedIndexPath;

@synthesize svc, selectedTabs;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                             target:self action:@selector(addItem:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *searchButton         = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
                                             target:self
                                             action:@selector(searchItem:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *editButton          = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit
                                             target:self action:@selector(editItem:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:editButton, searchButton, nil];

    //Initialize our table data source
    allCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    allSubjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    subjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    selectedTabs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.categories = [appDelegate activeCategories];
    self.subjects = [appDelegate activeSubjects];
    self.allCategories = [appDelegate categories];
    self.allSubjects = [appDelegate subjects];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Categories";

    [searchButton release];
    [editButton release];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

//- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
//{
//    return @"Category List";
//}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

    NSUInteger count = [self.categories count];
    NSLog(@"~~~numberOfRowsInSection: %lu", (unsigned long)count);

    return self.categories.count;

}        

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if(self.categories.count>0)
    {

        Category *cat = [self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"         category title = %@", cat.category_title);
        cell.textLabel.text = cat.category_title;

    } 
    else 
    {

        NSLog(@"      ERROR: self.categories has no objects in it!!!!");

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Also take a look at the log below. It looks like the view is being called randomly while the data is being loaded. This is probably linked to why the view doesn't open with all the data displayed.

```
2015-11-07 16:13:23.889 Quotes[11795:757246] getInitialDataToDisplay is loading data...
2015-11-07 16:13:23.896 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 1
2015-11-07 16:13:23.897 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 2
2015-11-07 16:13:23.898 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 3
2015-11-07 16:13:23.898 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 4
2015-11-07 16:13:23.899 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 5
2015-11-07 16:13:23.900 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 6
2015-11-07 16:13:23.900 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 7
2015-11-07 16:13:23.900 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 8
2015-11-07 16:13:23.901 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 9
2015-11-07 16:13:23.901 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 10
2015-11-07 16:13:23.902 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 11
2015-11-07 16:13:23.903 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 12
2015-11-07 16:13:23.903 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 13
2015-11-07 16:13:23.904 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 14
2015-11-07 16:13:23.904 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 15
2015-11-07 16:13:23.906 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 16
2015-11-07 16:13:23.906 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 17
2015-11-07 16:13:23.906 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 18
2015-11-07 16:13:23.907 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 19
2015-11-07 16:13:23.907 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 20
2015-11-07 16:13:23.908 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 21
2015-11-07 16:13:23.908 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 22
2015-11-07 16:13:23.910 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 23
2015-11-07 16:13:23.910 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 24
2015-11-07 16:13:23.911 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 25
2015-11-07 16:13:23.911 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 26
2015-11-07 16:13:23.912 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 27
2015-11-07 16:13:23.912 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 28
2015-11-07 16:13:23.913 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 29
2015-11-07 16:13:23.913 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 30
2015-11-07 16:13:23.913 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 31
2015-11-07 16:13:23.914 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 32
2015-11-07 16:13:23.914 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 33
2015-11-07 16:13:23.915 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 34
2015-11-07 16:13:23.915 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 35
2015-11-07 16:13:23.916 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 36
2015-11-07 16:13:23.916 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 37
2015-11-07 16:13:23.916 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 38
2015-11-07 16:13:23.917 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 39
2015-11-07 16:13:23.917 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 40
2015-11-07 16:13:23.918 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 41
2015-11-07 16:13:23.918 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 42
2015-11-07 16:13:23.918 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 43
2015-11-07 16:13:23.919 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 44
2015-11-07 16:13:23.919 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 45
2015-11-07 16:13:23.920 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 46
2015-11-07 16:13:23.920 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 47
2015-11-07 16:13:23.922 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 48
2015-11-07 16:13:23.922 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 49
2015-11-07 16:13:23.922 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 50
2015-11-07 16:13:23.923 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 51
2015-11-07 16:13:23.923 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 52
2015-11-07 16:13:23.924 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 53
2015-11-07 16:13:23.924 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 54
2015-11-07 16:13:23.924 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 55
2015-11-07 16:13:23.925 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 56
2015-11-07 16:13:23.925 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 57
2015-11-07 16:13:23.925 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 58
2015-11-07 16:13:23.926 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 59
2015-11-07 16:13:23.926 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 60
2015-11-07 16:13:23.927 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 61
2015-11-07 16:13:23.928 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 62
2015-11-07 16:13:23.928 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 63
2015-11-07 16:13:23.928 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 64
2015-11-07 16:13:23.929 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 65
2015-11-07 16:13:23.929 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 66
2015-11-07 16:13:23.929 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 67
2015-11-07 16:13:23.930 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 68
2015-11-07 16:13:23.930 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 69
2015-11-07 16:13:23.931 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 70
2015-11-07 16:13:23.931 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 71
2015-11-07 16:13:23.931 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 72
2015-11-07 16:13:23.932 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 73
2015-11-07 16:13:23.933 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 74
2015-11-07 16:13:23.933 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 75
2015-11-07 16:13:23.933 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 76
2015-11-07 16:13:23.934 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 77
2015-11-07 16:13:23.934 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 78
2015-11-07 16:13:23.935 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 79
2015-11-07 16:13:23.935 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 80
2015-11-07 16:13:23.936 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 81
2015-11-07 16:13:23.936 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 82
2015-11-07 16:13:23.937 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 83
2015-11-07 16:13:23.937 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 84
2015-11-07 16:13:23.937 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 85
2015-11-07 16:13:23.938 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 86
2015-11-07 16:13:23.939 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 87
2015-11-07 16:13:23.939 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 88
2015-11-07 16:13:23.940 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 89
2015-11-07 16:13:23.940 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 90
2015-11-07 16:13:23.940 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 91
2015-11-07 16:13:23.941 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 92
2015-11-07 16:13:23.942 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 93
2015-11-07 16:13:23.942 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 94
2015-11-07 16:13:23.942 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 95
2015-11-07 16:13:23.943 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 96
2015-11-07 16:13:23.943 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 97
2015-11-07 16:13:23.943 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 98
2015-11-07 16:13:23.944 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 99
2015-11-07 16:13:23.944 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 100
2015-11-07 16:13:23.945 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 101
2015-11-07 16:13:23.945 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 102
2015-11-07 16:13:40.838 Quotes[11795:757003] ~~~numberOfRowsInSection: 0
2015-11-07 16:13:40.838 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 103
2015-11-07 16:13:43.003 Quotes[11795:757003] ~~~numberOfRowsInSection: 0
2015-11-07 16:13:43.004 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 104
2015-11-07 16:13:43.971 Quotes[11795:757003] ~~~numberOfRowsInSection: 0
2015-11-07 16:13:43.972 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 105
2015-11-07 16:13:43.973 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 106
2015-11-07 16:13:43.973 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 107
2015-11-07 16:13:43.974 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 108
2015-11-07 16:13:43.974 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 109
2015-11-07 16:13:43.975 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 110
2015-11-07 16:13:43.975 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 111
2015-11-07 16:13:43.977 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 112
2015-11-07 16:13:43.977 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 113
2015-11-07 16:13:43.978 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 114
2015-11-07 16:13:43.979 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 115
2015-11-07 16:13:43.979 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 116
2015-11-07 16:13:43.980 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 117
2015-11-07 16:13:43.980 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 118
2015-11-07 16:13:44.971 Quotes[11795:757003] ~~~numberOfRowsInSection: 0
2015-11-07 16:13:44.972 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 119
2015-11-07 16:13:45.618 Quotes[11795:757003] ~~~numberOfRowsInSection: 0
2015-11-07 16:13:45.619 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 120
2015-11-07 16:13:45.620 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 121
2015-11-07 16:13:45.620 Quotes[11795:757246] appDelegate.quotes --- 122
```

Comment: where is startLoading called?

Comment: good question. 
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self startLoading];    
}

Comment: You have to init your Quote. Quote *q = [[Quote alloc] init]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't change the outcome. The q was still nil and the view controller still showed up empty after initial load.

Comment: If q is still nil even after you call init. There is something wrong with the Quote's init method. Can you post that code?

Comment: I posted that code above. I still haven't figured this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create the initial update for the data in the background, if you reload the data for your UITableView right after that, there is almost no chance that there is any data in the arrays yet since the values are gotten in the background.  When you have all of your values, in your background thread call:

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
 });`

You need to call that at the end of the background method when you have all values in your arrays, otherwise you won't have everything/anything in your arrays and it will show up with no data.  The reason you had data when you went back is because you call reloadData in your viewWillAppear method and at that point it must have gotten all values in the background.

EDIT:

In your QuoteDelegate.m file you will want to call this when you are done updating all of your arrays (userInfoDictionary is an NSDictionary of any info you want to make available to the method responding to the notification):

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"YourNotificationName" object:nil userInfo:userInfoDictionary];`

In your viewDidLoad method in the RootViewController.m file call:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourCustomMethodToImplementReloadDataIn) name:@"YourNotificationName" object:nil];`

Then in whatever you call the "yourCustomMethodToImplementReloadDataIn", just call this and you should get the results you want:

`[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: Where should I call the above? In my RootViewController or the AppDelegate?

Comment: With how you have this set up, you will more than likely need to set up a notification for when the table data is retrieved.  You will want to set the notification in the Quote.m file, and you will listen for it in the RootViewController file.  When the notification is posted you can then just call `[self.tableView reloadData];` but set that in a separate method.  I will make another answer if you want to know how to set the notification and listen for it.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm new to all this and appreciate your help. If you could lay this out in another answer that would be great.

Comment: After some trial and error I was able to get this to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to override Quote's init method.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // initialize member variables here
        _quote_id = nil;
        // etc...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I did that and now the Quote variable is not showing up as nil but the first view still shows up as blank. I walked through the code and all the data appears to be loading correctly. I'm looking into possible XIB issues with the new constraint requirements in Xcode 7. Any other ideas why this first screen could be showing up blank even though all the data is actually there? Switch to edit and cancel back to this screen then all the data shows up.

Comment: Can you show the code where you populate the views with your data?

Comment: I added this above. Also check out the log which shows the view is being called several times and the count is 0.